# Background-image not loading image with correct file path

Tags: html, css

I am new to JS and I'm making a game in HTML5/JS, and I need to set a background image for a div that is nested in another div, without overflow. I put the `background-image` property on the element, but the background is not appearing.

I haven't been able to find any other examples of this online, or how to fix it. The `background-image` property is showing up in the browser, and the file paths are correct.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="DivId" class="DivClass">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.DivClass {
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.75);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:47%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#DivId {
  background-image: url(../InventoryAssets/Key-trimmy.png);
}
```

Comment: You have a missing quotes at the end of DivClass, in the HTML code

Comment: If your background-image-container does no have any content in it, you need to set a min-height oder height property. Otherwise the div won't have an area to render the image

Comment: @luenib sorry for the confusion, I must have typed the code wrong

Comment: As @ChristophKern says just add a dimension to the #DivId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should keep the file in the same folder in which you html file is there and then try it for example

```
#DivId {
background-image: url(Key-trimmy.png);
}
```

I hope this helps you
or try

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('Key-trimmy.png')";
```

you can also add image in body tag in html

```
<body style="background-image: Key-trimmy.png;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest giving a height value to the div. Background images are not HTML content themselves.
For example:

```
 #DivId {
      background-image: url(../InventoryAssets/Key-trimmy.png);
      height: 500px;
    }
```